# How to enumerate SQL Server role members with Powershell?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, smo

I sent this question to ServerFault, but I'm wondering if it's really a programming question?

https://serverfault.com/questions/205515/how-to-enumerate-sql-server-role-members-with-powershell

Just wondered if you guys had any idea on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enumMembers()`  plus you went a little too deep.

```
foreach ($role in $db.Roles) 
{ 
    Write-Host $role.Name  
    foreach ( $member in $role.EnumMembers() ) 
    { 
        Write-Host "`t$member"
    } 
    Write-Host
}
```